# Unit testing break in foreach loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing

I'm trying to unit test the *cancel execution* scenario in a class conceptually similar to the following:

```cs
public class ContextExecutor
{
    public ContextExecutor(IContextRunner runner, IExecutionCanceler canceler)
    {
        this.runner = runner;
        this.canceler = canceler;
    }

    public void Execute(IEnumerable<IContext> contexts)
    {
        foreach (var ctx in contexts)
        {
            if (canceler.IsCanceled)
            {
                break;
            }

            runner.Run(ctx);
        }
    }

    readonly IContextRunner runner;
    readonly IExecutionCanceler canceler;
}

public interface IContextRunner 
{
    void Run(IContext context);
}

public interface IExecutionCanceler 
{
    bool IsCanceled { get; }
}
```

The test case I was after should go through the following steps:

1. start `ContextExecutor.Execute()` asynchronously somehow;
2. put that method execution on hold until something unlocks it from unit test code;
3. unlock execution and let it perform 1 (..or 2, or..) loop runs, anyway less than full enumerable length;
4. invoke canceling by setting `canceler.IsCanceled = true`;
5. unlock loop execution free;
6. wait synchronously for method completion;
7. assert that loop has been invoked the expected nr of times.

I got tangled up with controlling loop execution locking/unlocking from unit test code. Apart from starting `Execute()` in a new thread, I avoided using threading synchronization primitives (e.g. semaphores and locks). I also had to discard a `Task`-based approach, as I could not change signatures to apply `async/await` constructs. I tried to play with the following, but with no luck:

- inject a `yield`-powered function as `IEnumerable<IContext>` input parameter to hold loop on `foreach()` line, to release loop everytime another `yield` is hit, and try to control that from unit test code.
- inject a `IContextRunner runner` powered by a Reactive Extension `Subject` to hold loop on `runner.Run` line, to release loop everytime another `Subject.OnNext` is hit, and try to control that from unit test code.

For that matters, unit testing framework is NUnit, while NSubstitute is the mocking framework and FluentAssertion is the assertion library of choice. I know how to arrange/act/assert with those.

What is so evident that I missing? Thanks

**EDIT**

To provide an example of what has been tried, this is a `Task`-based approach made after posting question and reading @Peter Duniho helpful comment:

```
// in unit test class

ContextExecutor executor;
IContextRunner runner;
IExecutionCanceler canceler;
IRunnableContext[] runnableContexts;
int totalNrOfContexts;
int nrOfContextToRun;  // this will be < totalNrOfContexts
int actualNrOfContextRan;

[SetUp]
public virtual void before_each()
{
    // create instance under test, mock dependencies, dummy input data
    Initialize();

    RunScenarioAsync().Wait();
}

async Task RunScenarioAsync()
{
    // prepare mock IContextRunner so that for each input context:
    //  * there's a related TaskCompletionSource<Object> 
    //  * Run() increments actualNrOfContextRan
    //  * Run() performs taskSource.Task.Wait();
    List<TaskCompletionSource<Object>> runTaskSources = PrepareMockContextRunner();

    canceler.IsCanceled.Returns(false); // let execution go initially

    // queue up method under test to be processed asynchronously
    var executeTask = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        executor.Execute(runnableContexts);
    };

    // "unlock" some IContextRunner.Run() invocations,
    // for when they will be invoked
    for (int i = 0; i < nrOfContextToRun; i++)
    {
        runTaskSources[i].SetResult(null);

        await Task.Delay(0);  // tried also with Delay(1) and without this line at all
    }

    // flag to cancel execution
    canceler.IsCanceled.Returns(true);

    // unlock all remaining IContextRunner.Run() invocations,
    // again for when/if they will be invoked
    for (int i = nrOfContextToRun; i < totalNrOfContexts; i++)
    {
        runTaskSources[i].SetResult(null);

        await Task.Delay(0);
    }

    // wait until method under test completes
    await executeTask;
}

[Test]
public void it_should_only_run_until_cancel()
{
    int expected = nrOfContextToRun;
    int actual = actualNrOfContextRan;

    actual.Should().Be(expected);
}
```

The problem I have here (and similar to other approaches tried) is about giving and regain control to/from the method under test in a predictable way (that is, synchronizing).
Here, if there's no `await Task.Delay()` or if delay is 0ms, only 1 context is actually ran: the method under test has no chance to run the 2nd and 3rd one, it finds the canceling flag too soon. If delay is 1ms, method executes more context than expected before actually detecting the flag. Also tried with ticks instead of ms, but in my experience playing with delays usually means you're doing something wrong.

Comment: While not ideal, you can always wrap `async Task` methods in other method signatures (i.e. compatible with e.g. `IContextRunner` interface) for testing purposes. It's not clear why you decided to avoid sync primitives. And the other options you say you tried should be workable as well. As stated, your question is too broad. Please decide which approach you want to use, then show a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces whatever problem you actually had with that approach.

Comment: Just added an example approach with Tasks and the issue I met

Comment: The method you are trying to test is a synchronized method. you don't need any ׳System.Task׳ in the UT.... you should use a mocking framework such as Moq...

Comment: I'm already using a mocking framework, NSubstitute. Sorry I did not get the point about synchronized method: how would you be able to run some method from main code, and at the same time interact with it from unit test code?